# nodejs mssql not returning data on PUT

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have following scenario:

**user.js**

```
const express        = require('express');
const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
const app            = express();
const db             = require('./sql');    

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/v1/users', async function (req, res) {
    res.json(await db.post_newUser(req.body));
});
```

**sql.js**

```
var connectionString = {
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'server',
    database: 'db',
    options: {
        encrypt: false
    }
}
const sql = require('mssql');

module.exports = {
    post_newUser: async function(data) { 
        sql.connect(connectionString)
            .then(pool => {            
                return pool.request()
                           .input('name', sql.VarChar, data.name)
                           .input('mail', sql.VarChar, data.mail)
                           .execute('sp_post_newUser');
            })
            .then(result => {
                return JSON.parse(result);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                // ... error checks
            })        
    }
}
```

**sp_post_newUser**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_post_newUser] 
    @name varchar(100),
    @mail varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[users] ([name],[mail]) VALUES (@name, @mail)

    DECLARE @userProfile varchar(MAX)
    SET @userProfile = (SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail=@mail FOR JSON AUTO)

    SELECT [userProfile] = @userProfile;
END
```

*NOTE: I simplified the code to keep it short. Any syntax error should be ignored. :-)*

My stored procedure is storing the data in the database. At the same time, it returns a table that should be returned by the api, but it always comes blank.

Comment: That's way overcomplicated code. If you want to return the new entry, just write `SELECT * from users where ...`, no FOR JSON, no assignment to variables.

Comment: also tried that, but the api also didn't gave the result back

Comment: SQL queries work. If something in the code doesn't, the code needs fixing, not the query. Overcomplicating queries introduces problems, it doesn't fix them. Databases don't return JSON, so what does the *original* code look like, before you tried to convert the result to JSON?

Comment: I know that the SQL query works. My question is about the nodejs code.

Comment: The original query can return multiple rows, if there are multiple rows the same email. You can use the [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in INSERT to return the new values, eg `INSERT .... OUTPUT inserted.* VALUES (...)`

Comment: I know that. As I said, I simplified the whole thing in the question to keep it short. SQL is not the problem at all. SQL is working as expected. The nodejs code isn't.

Comment: Both the query and code do something unusual - handle the results as JSON. Perhaps some syntax error that *does* matter prevent the code from working. Perhaps `parse` fails because the response *is* a table/cursor, not a raw string that can be parsed. At the very least you should get the value of the `userProfile` column

Comment: Both query and code need fixing. Trying to treat results as JSON *caused* the problem. You can't avoid handling the result rows and columns, unless you use an ORM to return ready-made objects

Comment: I am using the same approach when I am only getting data (not posting) and it works fine. I also tried with and without parsing.

Comment: `JSON.parse(result);` will never work. `result` is not a string. Have you tried debugging the code, inspect what `result` actually is? Before trying to treat this as JSON, have you tried using code that reads the *rows* and *columns*?

Comment: The `result` is a complex, with a `recordsets` property returning all result recordsets (if there are multiple SELECTs) and `recordset` that returns the first of them. The `recordset` can be treated as an array of rows. Columns appear as properties on the row, so `result.recordset[0].userProfile` is probably needed to return the single result column. It would be easier if you *didn't* try to use JSON for this  and tried eg to return the row directly, or return a new object with the specific columns you want. No need to serialize just to deserialize before returning the entire row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem in post_newUser function. This function is not return data. try code like this

```
module.exports = {
    post_newUser: function(data) { 
        return sql.connect(connectionString)
        ...
```

Or rewrite it on pure await/async

```
module.exports = {
    post_newUser: async function(data) { 
        const pool = await sql.connect(connectionString);
        const result = await pool.request()
                       .input('name', sql.VarChar, data.name)
                       .input('mail', sql.VarChar, data.mail)
                       .execute('sp_post_newUser');
        return JSON.parse(result);
        ...
```

Comment: Other remove `.catch(err => {}` section. Exception must reach `res.json(await db.post_newUser(req.body));`

Comment: The problem is that `result` is not a string, it contains the `recordsets` with the result *rows*.

Comment: The second option with await/async worked with a small adjustment:
```JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))```
This sounds stupid and I will improve that, but at least I am on the right way now. Thanks, @YaroslavGaponov!

Comment: I think `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` is equal `data`

Comment: ...and not `data` but `result`

Comment: @DaniloKörber what you did was convert the `result` object into `JSON` only to parse it back, and return it as is. You could have written just `return result;` instead.